# get data from another table matching with name laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Before I start here are some translation, since I'm not using english for my code:

**Penyedia = Vendor**

**Pekerjaan = Work**

So I have two table, Vendor Table and Work Table. Each Vendor can have multiple of Works, and each Work can be own by only one Vendor. It supposed to be one to many relationship. Here is my table

**Vendor Table**
[image: vendro table]

**Work Table**
[image: work table]

So, I'm using LARAVEL as my framework. I have created a vendor table with an action button, that I want it to function which if click, it will show the work (pekerjaan) list owned by the exact vendor name. As you can see from the table above I added the vendor name (nama) to the "Work Table" in my database. How could I do this function to work? I'm new to this "Eloquent" in Laravel.

Here is my model files:

**Pekerjaan.php**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Pekerjaan extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function penyedia(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Penyedia');
   }

}
```

**Penyedia.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Penyedia extends Eloquent
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function pekerjaan(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Pekerjaan');
   }
}
```

**AdminController.php**

```
    public function showpekerjaan(){
        $penyedia = penyedia::all();

        return view('admin.showpekerjaan', compact('penyedia'));
    }
```

**tabelnilai_pekerjaan.blade.php** (I want to show this work table according to the vendor)

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Tabel Nilai Pekerjaan</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                  <table id="tabelpekerjaan" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">No.</th>
                        <th>Paket Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th>Nama Perusahaan</th>
                        <th>Lokasi Pekerjaan</th>
                        <th>HPS</th>
                        <th>Nilai Kontrak</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px">Aksi</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @php $no = 1; @endphp
                      @foreach ($penyedia as $penyedias)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$penyedias->pekerjaan->pekerjaan}}</td>
                        <td>{{$penyedias->pekerjaan->nama}}</td>
                        <td>{{$penyedias->pekerjaan->lokasi}}</td>
                        <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaans->pekerjaan->hps,0,',',',')}}</td>
                        <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaans->pekerjaan->nilai_kontrak,0,',',',')}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
  
            
    </div>
</section>
```

Is there anything that I need to add or edit or change? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print array as string. Your pekerjaan() relation has hasmany property and it returns array. If you like to display all pekerjaan, you need to run a second loop inside a loop. and if you need to display only one, you can simply do

```
<td>{{$penyedias->pekerjaan[0]->pekerjaan}}</td>
```

To display all pekerjaan, you can loop on $penyedias->pekerjaan like:

```
  @php $no = 1; @endphp
                  @foreach ($penyedia as $penyedias) 
                   @foreach($penyedias->pekerjaan as $pekerjaan)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                    <td>{{$pekerjaan->pekerjaan}}</td>
                    <td>{{$penyedias->nama}}</td>
                    <td>{{$pekerjaan->lokasi}}</td>
                    <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaan->hps,0,',',',')}}</td>
                    <td>Rp. {{number_format($pekerjaan->nilai_kontrak,0,',',',')}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outline-primary">Edit</a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                   @endforeach
                  @endforeach
```

And change  $penyedia = penyedia::all(); on your controller to  $penyedia = Penyedia::all();

Comment: Yes I want to show all pekerjaan that have the same penyedia name. May I know how to achieve the loop? Where should I put the loop logic? Thank you.

Comment: And also I got the Error like this when trying your suggestion `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pekerjaans.penyedia_id' in 'where clause'` @Mad an

Comment: can you please list full info of both the db tables with column that contains related id

Comment: Here is my updated database, I already included a foreign key which is the ID of the 'penyedia'(vendor). Now my problem is, how to show the list of table 'pekerjaan'(work) based on the ID of the penyedia(vendor) https://imgur.com/a/ZvM2Ee9 @Mad an